# Open A PDF file on button click

Tags: c#, file, pdf, windows-runtime

I want to open a pdf file in winRT app(metro style app) by clicking on a button the file should open in windows8 default reader. I tried this code, where button click method name is `DefaultLaunch_click()`:

```
async void DefaultLaunch_click()
{
   // Path to the file in the app package to launch
  string imageFile = @"images\ret.png";

 // Get the image file from the package's image directory
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);



if (file != null)
{
// Set the recommended app
  var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
  options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = “Contoso.FileApp_8wknc82po1e”;
  options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = “Contoso File App”;




  // Launch the retrieved file pass in the recommended app 
  // in case the user has no apps installed to handle the file
  bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
  if (success)
  {
     // File launched
  }
  else
  {
     // File launch failed
  }
  }
    else
    {
      // Could not find file
    }
    }
```

It worked for .png file but i want for .pdf file i replaced 1.png with M.pdf(after including it in images folder) and set the build content of M.pdf to Embedded Resource , run the program but it showed error that

```
**The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me after I set PDF file build action to content and copy always to output directory.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imageFile = @"images\somepdffile.pdf";

        // Get the image file from the package's image directory
        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
        if (file != null)
        {
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                // File launch failed
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Could not find file
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it worked:-) i also tried it worked fine :-) . Thankyouu...:)

Comment: Can you please ahve a look at it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011326/open-pdf-file-in-emulator