# Open PDF file in Emulator

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have this code :

```
private async void LaunchPDF(string name) 
        {
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(name);

            if (file != null)
            {
                // Set the option to show the picker
                var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

                // Launch the retrieved file
                bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
                if (success)
                {
                    // File launched
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched");
                }
                else
                {
                    // File launch failed
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched Failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not find file
                Debug.WriteLine("File not found");
            }
        }
```

This method is called here :

```
private void longListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyObject item  =  longListSelector.SelectedItem as MyObject;
            LaunchPDF("Data/PDF/" + item.SubTitle + ".pdf");
        }
```

I am testing on `Windows Phone 8 Emulator`, When i click on the item in  the longlist selector i get the below error:

```
{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyApp.Classes.Views.PDFPage.<LaunchPDF>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)}
```

How to fix this ? what am i doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I have set this as well , change it's build action.

Right click on PDF document.

Click on properties.

Change Build Action from None to Content

Comment: Minimally, you need to use proper Windows Path separators. `LaunchPdF(@"Data\PDFs\" + item.SubTitle + ".pdf");`

Comment: @WiredPrairie i tried that as well but stil not working, and also how can i test it on emulator ? if the pdf is opening or not ?

Comment: You can't install apps currently ... don't you have access to a physical device where you could test it?